# Vertically-centering multiple TikZ pictures, preserving baseline height

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've often need to write out equations between pictures, which are drawn using TikZ. However, to display them properly, I have two requirements: any common features must be on the same horizontal line, and the diagrams as a whole must be vertically centered with respect to any = signs separating them.

Here's a picture of the effect I want:
[image]
Here's a picture of the effect I *don't* want, but which is easily achieved:
[image]

Of course, for a particular diagram, it's just a couple of lines of code to get the effect I want. But ideally, I'd specify the position of the labels - perhaps by setting the baseline of the diagrams to the label A - and then the rest should happen automatically.

There are many ways I can achieve this manually: for example, increasing the size of the bounding box for the smaller diagram to artificially force it to have the same height as the larger one; or manually setting the baseline of the images to exactly the point which I want aligned with the baseline of the = sign. But both of these are fiddly, and none are robust against future changes of the diagrams.

Here's the code to produce the second image above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)
    node [above] {$A$}
    to [out=down, in=down] (1,0)
    node [above] {$A^*$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{aligned}
=
\begin{aligned}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)
    node [above] {$A$}
    to [out=down, in=up] (1,-1)
    to [out=down, in=down] (0,-1)
    to [out=up, in=down] (1,0)
    node [above] {$A^*$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Another try. My basic idea is to have a list of the whole equation, then to map over that list so that the tikz pictures are `\vcenter`ed to the tallest of the bunch, while the normal mathematical objects are passed as-is. Please note that I haven't tested this (much):

```
\catcode`@=11
\input lambda.sty
\input tikz

\def\Unravel#1{#1\Unravel@{}}
\def\Unravel@#1{#1\Foldr\Spaceize{}}
\def\Spaceize#1#2{ #1#2}

\newdimen\tallest
\newcount\index

\def\TypesetThem#1{%
  \advance\index by 1
  \TeXif{\ifodd\index }{\vcenter to\tallest{\hbox{$#1$}\vss}}{#1}}

\def\FindTallest#1{%
  \setbox0\vbox{\hbox{$#1$}}%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0>\tallest\tallest=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\fi}

\def\SameHeight#1{%
  \index=0
  \tallest=0pt
  \Unravel{\Map\FindTallest{#1}}
  \Unravel{\Map\TypesetThem{#1}}}

\def\MyTikZList{\Listize[
  {\tikz\draw (0,0)
    node[above] {$A$}
    to[out=down,in=down] (1,0)
    node[above] {$A^*$};},
  =,
  {\tikz\draw (0,0)
    node[above] {$A$}
    to[out=down,in=up] (1,-1)
    to[out=down,in=down] (0,-1)
    to[out=up,in=down] (1,0)
    node[above] {$A^*$};},
  +,
  {\tikz\draw (0,0)
    node[above] {$A$}
    to[out=down,in=up] (1,-1)
    to[out=down,in=down] (0,-1)
    to[out=up,in=down] (1,0)
    node[above] {$A^*$};},
  -,
  {\tikz\draw (0,0)
    node[above] {$A$}
    to[out=down,in=down] (1,0)
    node[above] {$A^*$};},
  ]}

$$
  \SameHeight\MyTikZList
$$

\bye
```

The tikz pictures needed to be grouped.

[image]

Comment: Hi @morbusg, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, that's not what I want. As I showed in the example image, the = sign has to be  at the centre of the tallest image.

Comment: Thanks for your update. All these ideas work - as I say in the question, the difficulty isn't finding some way to do this. The difficulty is finding a way to do it which doesn't require specifying more than the logically minimal amount of information. In particular, I will be editing these pictures, and I don't want to have to change any auxiliary elements which are just put in place to make it align correctly. Your solution fails this test - if I change the height of the right-hand picture, I have to move my extra invisible coordinate.

Comment: @Jamie: When all else fails: `\box` it `;-)`

Comment: Hi morbusg. Can you help me unpack your latest suggestion? How does it know to align them correctly with respect to one another?

Comment: @Jamie: ah, of course! I'm sorry, I'll add information.

Comment: @Jamie: I forgot to mention that my last example has the added benefit that if you need to frequently use the same images over and over again, you can just `\copy0` and `\copy1` instead of `\box0` and `\box1` to use them in some other place later.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really reuse images. The problem with this solution still is that it is not automatic - if the relative heights of the boxes change, I'd need to redo the placement code. Am I right?

Comment: Well, I just tested it, and if I make the first box deeper than the second box, the positioning becomes wrong... the equals sign is still given at half the depth of the right-hand diagram, whereas it should be at half the depth of the _tallest_ diagram.

Comment: Ok ... but in general, I could have lots of these diagrams, not just two!

Answer (score 4):

This is not the optimal solution but required manual adjustment is not so much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

An entangled equation and required meaningless text just to justify this sentence length. 
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\node (A) at (0,0) {\tikz{\draw (0,0)
    node [above] {$A$}
    to [out=down, in=down] (1,0)
    node [above] {$A^*$};}};
\node[anchor=north west] (B) at ($(A.north east)+(1em,0)$) {
\tikz{\draw (0,0)
    node [above] {$A$}
    to [out=down, in=up] (1,-1)
    to [out=down, in=down] (0,-1)
    to [out=up, in=down] (1,0)
    node [above] {$A^*$};
}
};
\node[left] (equa) at (B.west) {=};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Basically you draw two distinct sides of the equation via nodes and then align them from their top limit and squeeze an equal sign in between.

[image]

Comment: It took quite longer than a minute,sorry :)

Comment: Thanks percusse! An interesting solution. But still less automatic than I would like, as you say. In particular, if I edited the left diagram so that it became taller than the right diagram, the placement code would again need re-editing.

Comment: @JamieVicary Not necessarily, you only need to change `(B.west)` to `(A.east)` in the last line

Comment: Right - that's what I mean about "re-editing"!

Answer (score 1):

How about `\raisebox{-\height/2}{<tikz code>}`?

[image]

```
\begin{equation}
    \raisebox{-\height/2}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)
        node [above] {$A$}
        to [out=down, in=down] (1,0)
        node [above] {$A^*$};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    = \raisebox{-\height/2}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)
        node [above] {$A$}
        to [out=down, in=up] (1,-1)
        to [out=down, in=down] (0,-1)
        to [out=up, in=down] (1,0)
        node [above] {$A^*$};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{equation}
```

It's not exactly versatile, i.e. it doesn't allow alignment w.r.t. common features in different `TikZ` pictures but it certainly manages the vertical alignment (which might be all others stumbling upon this post are looking for).